# Left align entire array environment

Tags: arrays

I want to create a notation section a la the [Matrix Cookbook (PDF)](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf). Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the Matrix Cookbook.]

I can create this using an array, so `\begin{array}{r l}` but then the whole array is centered. How can I left align the entire environment?

Comment: Do you write it by hand or is it generate with the help of some package such as `nomencl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}` at the end of your `array` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{r l}
aaaa & d \\
bb & eeee \\
ccc & fff
\end{array}
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill} % here it is
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can push it even closely by removing column space from the left with `@{}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{@{}r l} % at-expression here
aaaa & d \\
bb & eeee \\
ccc & fff
\end{array}
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill} % here it is
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]